# CMake cannot find freeglut on windows in Clion

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, clion

I've been stuck for a while now and I can't figure out how to get freeglut working. I thought I knew what it was asking me to do, so I added that set(prefix_path) line but it didn't do anything. Am I supposed to write my own freeglut-config.cmake or what?

Note: I am using the freeglut for MinGW package from this [website](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)

CMake File:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(HW1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES Triangle.cpp)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/freeglut")

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED STATIC)
find_package(FREEGLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(OPENGL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${FREEGLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${FREEGLUT_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${GLEW_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${FREEGLUT_DEFINITIONS} ${GLEW_DEFINITIONS} ${OPENGL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(HW1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(HW1 ${FREEGLUT_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Full error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindFREEGLUT.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "FREEGLUT",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FREEGLUT" with any
  of the following names:

    FREEGLUTConfig.cmake
    freeglut-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "FREEGLUT" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "FREEGLUT_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "FREEGLUT" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Answer (score 3):

If your application is **GLUT-compatible**, that it doesn't use any extension of freeglut, then it is better to search `GLUT` instead of `FREEGLUT`:

```
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
```

"Find" script used by this command is already shipped into CMake distro, and it searches freeglut too.

(Note, that with that command variables for include directories and linking libraries are `GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR` and `GLUT_LIBRARY` correspondingly).

If your application requires **exactly freeglut** (that is, uses some of its extensions *incompatible* with other GLUT implementations), you need to **ship your package** with `FindFREEGLUT.cmake` script and adjust *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* variable correspondingly:

```
# Assuming you have <source-dir>/cmake/FindFREEGLUT.cmake
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(FREEGLUT REQUIRED)
```

You may find existing script in the net, or write it by yourself, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882695/cmake-finds-the-correct-library-but-vc-attempts-to-link-with-something-else).

---

In any case, if you have freeglut installed into non-system location, you need to hint CMake about that. E.g., by adjusting *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH*.

Comment: I'm not sure that helped, now I'm getting a different error: https://hastebin.com/cuzohiwada.vbs. I used this guys find.cmake https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindFreeGLUT.cmake

Comment: Look like your libraries are **incompatible** with MinGW. Note, that there is undefined references to glew functions, these are unrelated to GLUT or freeglut.

Comment: So the provided windows binaries (http://glew.sourceforge.net/) won't work? I'll have to compile my own from source?

Comment: Yes, just *Windows* binaries are incompatible with MinGW. You need binaries specifically built for MinGW. See that [blogpost](https://bruceoutdoors.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/glew-for-mingw-in-windows/) and SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005076/building-glew-on-windows-with-mingw) it refers to.